# Replacing SVG element (path) keeping same size/coordinates

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I need to replace part of SVG image (map of hall seats) and it doesn't work as I would expect.

I have `<g transform="translate(383.25,-48.882672)"><g ..` node containing few `rect` and `path` elements which build an icon. I can find `g` by class with jQuery and `.html(other_path_content)` which makes content appear in the original size (too big to fit the original item spot). When I resize new icon `<path d=..` manually and html it again, it goes off the place and appears in different location than original icon.

The problem here is that SVG images I get are random so I can't calculate place of the original icon and transform it to be there as it will be different everytime.

Is that possible to somehow calculate position of the original element and its size (mind it contains of few rects and pathes) and put new one on exact same place? Or maybe I'm missing something in my approach (do I need to re-init svg after appending new node etc.)?

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson

I've tried getBBox and setting attributes to the inserted "path" icon, attributes are set,  however nothing actually changed, icon is still in the position/size it was when inserted

Comment: Edit the question and show us the code so we can see what you're trying to do.